# google drive files permission updation

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

I have a file in my google drive, How can I update the permissions for that file in python.
Since I am very new to programming, please suggest some possible solutions.

```
import json
import requests

FILE_ID = '###############'
access_token = '##############'
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+ FILE_ID +'/permissions'

meta_data = {
"type": "user",
"emailAddress": 'user@gmail.com',
"role": "writer"
}

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token} 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(meta_data))
```

This is what I tried but I am getting "permission type required" error.

Comment: No I tried some other way and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following Googles [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)  then you should be able to use the following code.

from apiclient import errors
    # ...

```
def update_permission(service, file_id, permission_id, new_role):
  """Update a permission's role.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to update permission for.
    permission_id: ID of the permission to update.
    new_role: The value 'owner', 'writer' or 'reader'.

  Returns:
    The updated permission if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  try:
    # First retrieve the permission from the API.
    permission = service.permissions().get(
        fileId=file_id, permissionId=permission_id).execute()
    permission['role'] = new_role
    return service.permissions().update(
        fileId=file_id, permissionId=permission_id, body=permission).execute()
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
  return None
```

Comment: If it is wrong sorry, Is it possible to do it with the access tokens available?

Comment: The client library will retrieve the access token for you you won't need to worry about it.    Can you clarify what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Access token is already retrieved. The rest of the process like creating folder, checking for files and uploading files to the drive has been done using the access token only.